# Binding individual property based of sqlite local database

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have created a ListView with items based on data saved in database. Its computer list with few properties as name, ipAdress, port and selected. If selected = true computer is marked as default and I need to change his appearance in ListView.

I need to create a binding to property which isnt part of the table.

I have simple list of computers (XAML)

```
<ListView x:Name="CompListView" HasUnevenRows="true" Grid.Row="1" SeparatorColor="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding ComputerList}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComputerItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid  Padding="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ComputerName}" Grid.Row="1" Font="20" TextColor="{Binding Selected_Color}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding IPAddress}" Grid.Row="0" Font="20" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  TextColor="{Binding Selected_Color}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Port}" Grid.Row="1" Font="13" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  TextColor="{Binding Selected_Color}"/>
                                <Image Source="computerpng.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest = "24" HeightRequest = "24" HorizontalOptions = "Start"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Base computer View connected to database.

```
 public class BaseComputerView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Computer _computer;

    public INavigation _navigation;
    public IComputer _computerRepository;

    public string ComputerName
    {
        get => _computer.ComputerName;
        set
        {
            _computer.ComputerName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Computer_Name");
        }
    }

    public string IPAddress
    {
        get => _computer.IPAddress;
        set
        {
            _computer.IPAddress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IPAddress");
        }
    }

    public string Port
    {
        get => _computer.Port;
        set
        {
            _computer.Port = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Port");
        }
    }

    public bool Selected
    {
        get => _computer.Selected;
        set
        {
            _computer.Selected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }
```

Based on _Selected I added property "Selected_Color" within the same class. Goal is to change back color of controls if the item is selected.

```
    public string Selected_Color
    {
        get
        {
            string Text_Color = string.Empty;
            try
            {

                if (Selected == true)
                {
                    Text_Color = "#33cc33";
                }
                else
                {
                    Text_Color = "#000000";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "#000000";
            }

            return Text_Color;
        }
    }
```

This code however looks up for property "Selected_Color" in Computer table, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use the `Ignore` attribute to tell SQLite to ignore your new property

```
[Ignore]
public string Selected_Color
```

alternately, you could use a [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to set the color based on the `Selected` property

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer,
 I figured it out by adding Selected_Color as Computer Table property.

```
[Table("Computer")]
public class Computer
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public string Selected_Color
    {
        get
        {
            string Text_Color = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (Selected == true)
                {
                    //Green color
                    Text_Color = "#33cc33";
                }
                else
                {
                    Text_Color = "#000000";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "#000000";
            }

            return Text_Color;
        }
    }
}
```

[App_ComputerList_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytr8n.png)
Works fine until I open one of the computers for edit and come back to computer list. What is weird is fact that I get Java exception not for the first time I do that but only for the second time. So I am able to open one of the items and came back to computer list. If I repeat that then I get [this Java exception.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaehP.png)

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to add answer for everyone who would fight with similar problem, that I found a better way to do this. You can define data templates based on your property and then use it to draw your Listview like this. Difference in this case is textcolor of the labels.

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedComputer">
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding ComputerName}" Grid.Row="1" Font="20" TextColor="Green" />
                <Label Text="{Binding IPAddress}" Grid.Row="0" Font="20" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  TextColor="Green"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Port}" Grid.Row="1" Font="13" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  TextColor="Green"/>
                <Image Source="computerpng.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest = "24" HeightRequest = "24" HorizontalOptions = "Start"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Computer">
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding ComputerName}" Grid.Row="1" Font="20" TextColor="Black" />
                <Label Text="{Binding IPAddress}" Grid.Row="0" Font="20" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  TextColor="Black"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Port}" Grid.Row="1" Font="13" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  TextColor="Black"/>
                <Image Source="computerpng.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest = "24" HeightRequest = "24" HorizontalOptions = "Start"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
        <local:ComputerTemplateSelector x:Key="ComputerTemplateSelector" SelectedComputer="{StaticResource SelectedComputer}" Computer="{StaticResource Computer}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Template selector:

```
public class ComputerTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SelectedComputer { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate Computer { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((SQLite_Database.Computer)item).Selected == true ? SelectedComputer : Computer;
    }
}
```